# Twilio Parallel Process Result Page Update

Tags: twilio, polling

I'm wanting to update a div or some area on a page that allows the user to progress, after a Twilio text goes out and receives either a 1 (true) or 0 (false) from a remote user.  I'd like to give the user 5 minutes to answer the text, and have the page display the conditional result based on that answer.

Anybody know of a way to poll a result in order to display the two options?  The user sends back a 1 to Twilio, which somehow goes to my server with parameters.  I'm still learning how that can be done.

So I am looking for two items:

- How to receive parameters from remote SMS using Twilio, passed to my server page, basically text number, sessionID, and user choice (1 or 0)
- same page display of updated response from above.  I'd like to not rely on page refresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When you receive an SMS message on a Twilio phone number, Twilio makes an HTTP request to your application, at a URL that you supply, with all the details about the message, including the number it was from and the body of the message.

I would recommend checking out the [quick start guides](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart) that we have on the site that will get you up and running [sending](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages) and [receiving messages using Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/twilio_request).

Once you've got the receiving messages bit sorted you then need to connect that incoming message to the browser the user was using. I'd take a look at either [Server Sent Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events) (which [I wrote about in a different context here](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/06/real-time-rails-4-using-server-sent-events-with-authy-onetouch.html)) or [web sockets](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/), both ways of connecting the server to the browser without needing to poll or refresh. You'll have to figure out how to create channels for your users so that they only receive their own update to the page.

Comment: HI Phil.  The polling bit was on the web browser side for a completely different user.  Essentially here's the workflow:

Comment: Think you missed a bit ;)

Comment: Ya I'm tired.  Thanks for the notes.  Exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: Oh, ha, ok cool. Glad I could help. Do give me a shout (well, I'm always checking SO) if you have any other issues.

Comment: Using Sinatra, it's very difficult to test the receiving post.  Any suggestions how I can test a headless page on a server?

Comment: What do you mean by test it? Have you looked at apps like [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) or [Hurl](https://www.hurl.it/)?

Comment: I checked the logs and it required 'tilt/erb' directly.  So that is now fixed, but Twilio is not parsing properly.  [See pic](http://www.pints.com/img/p2.png)

Comment: Hey @Rich_F, might be easier to take this out of the comments section here. Want to email me on philnash@twilio.com with an example of your code and I can try to see what's going on?